# Linked List in C with header node

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

> The type definition of the list is in linkedList.h as usual.

```
 #ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
 #define LINKEDLIST_H

 typedef struct snode {
        int value;  
        struct snode *next; 
 } snodeType;

 typedef struct hnode {int count;
        snodeType *first;
        snodeType *last; 
 } sList;

 sList* create_sList(void);
 int insert_element_s(sList *L, snodeType *p, int value);
 int delete_element_s(sList *L, snodeType *p); 
 sList* merge_lists(sList *L1, sList *L2);

 #endif /* LINKEDLIST_H */
```

Question is:

> sList * create_sList(void)  creates the list and returns it to the
>   caller. It has to allocate memory for the header node, initialize the
>   fields in the struct hnode.

```
sList* create_sList(void) {

    sList *list = NULL;
    list->first  = (sList*)malloc(sizeof(snodeType));
    list->last  = (sList*)malloc(sizeof(snodeType));

/*  2nd option
    sList *list = NULL;
    node = malloc(sizeof(snodeType));
    node->next= NULL;
    list->first = node;
    list->last = node;
*/

    return list;
}
```

I need to just initiate this linked list, is there somebody who know how?

Comment: What do you mean by initiate the list?

Comment: `sList* create_sList(void) { sList *list = malloc(sizeof(*list)); list->count = 0; list->last = list->first = NULL; return list; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should just be:

```
sList * create_sList(void)
{
  sList *list = malloc(sizof *list);
  if(list != NULL)
  {
    list->count = 0;
    list->first = list->last = NULL;
  }
  return list;
}
```

This returns a list head with no elements, i.e. an empty list header.

Comment: @Garf365 Thanks, didn't see it due to the indent. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To "initiate"(create) the linked list you should allocate the head pointer by doing

```
sList* create_sList(void) {
  sList *list = NULL;
  if ((list = malloc(sizeof(sList))) == NULL) // always check your mallocs  
    return (NULL);
  if ((list->first = malloc(sizeof(snodeType))) == NULL)
    return (NULL);
  bzero(list->first, sizeof(snodeType));
  list->last = list->first;
  return (list);
}
```

then use `int insert_element_s(sList *L, snodeType *p, int value);`, *p being either the last or the first element of list, *L being list and value being the value. :)

Comment: Why allocate memory for first node ? It's an empty list, so, `list->first` and `list->last` should be equal to `NULL` and `list->count` should be equal to zero

Comment: Didn't realise you wanted an empty list sorry :)